# After adding component HomeComponent with selector app-home, when I run ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2017, app-home can't be seen

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

When I added Component to my ASP.NET MVC project using GIT by `ng g Component Home` and took selector `app-home` in index.cshtml nothing happened.

this is home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    template: '',
})
export class HomeComponent { name = 'Home'; }
```

this is _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>System.import('/src/app/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <my-app></my-app>
    <app-home></app-home>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and this is home.component.html

```
<p>home works!</p>
```

Why?

Comment: change `template: '',` to `templateUrl: './home.component.html',`

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

this was solved by adding `bootstrap: [HomeComponent]` in app.module.ts

file was like that

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [AppComponent, BrowserModule],
    declarations: [HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when I changed it to that

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

everything worked well